# A way to show that if $y''(x) +y(x)=0$ then $y(x)=\cos (x)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How can I show that if $y''(x)+y(x)=0$ then $y(x)=\cos(x)$. I found this out by intuition but is there a algebraic way to show this?

Comment: The general solution is $A\cos x+B\sin x$. For $\cos x$ you need certain specific initial conditions.

Comment: Thats not what I meant, for example $-cos(x) +cos(x)=0$ because $y(x)=cos(x)$ and $y^{''}(x)=-cos(x)$ What I am looking for is a proof that generalizes this idea.

Comment: @adam The point is that the claim isn't correct: The sine function (as well as infinitely many other functions) satisfy the given equation.

Comment: Ahhh I see, but is there a way to do this with sepeartion of variables is what I am looking for

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiply by $2y'$ and integrate:
$$
2y'y''+2yy'=0\implies y'^{\,2}+y^2=a^2
$$
for some constant $a$. Separate variables and integrate
$$
\begin{align}
\int\mathrm{d}x&=\int\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\sqrt{a^2-y^2}}\\
x&=b-\cos^{-1}(y/a)
\end{align}
$$
Thus, $y=a\cos(x-b)=a\cos(b)\cos(x)+a\sin(b)\sin(x)$.

Comment: This is more of the solution I expected to see. But they are both good

Comment: So I am guessing to show that $y^{''} +y^{'} + y=0$ can be done the same way to find that $y(x)=e^{rt}$?

Comment: @adam: a similar approach, but using integrating factors, can be used.

Comment: Perhaps multiplying by $2yy^{'}$?

Comment: @adam: Factor the DE as
$$
0=y''+y'+y=(D-\lambda)(D-\bar\lambda)y
$$
where $\lambda=e^{2\pi i/3}$. Using the integrating factor $e^{-\lambda x}$, we get
$$
(D-\lambda)y=f\iff D(e^{-\lambda x}y)=e^{-\lambda x}f\implies y=e^{\lambda x}\int e^{-\lambda x}f\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
Thus, $(D-\bar\lambda)y=a\,e^{\lambda x}$ and
$$
\begin{align}
y
&=e^{\bar\lambda x}\int e^{-\bar\lambda x}a\,e^{\lambda x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{a}{\lambda-\bar\lambda}e^{\lambda x}+b\,e^{\bar\lambda x}\\
&=a'\,e^{\lambda x}+b\,e^{\bar\lambda x}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 4):

We can solve this as:

$$\lambda^2  + 1 = 0 \rightarrow \lambda_{1,2} = \pm~i$$

You can write this out as:

$$y(x) = c_1e^{\lambda_1 x}+c_2e^{\lambda_2 x} = c_1e^{-i~x} + c_2e^{i~x}$$

Now you can use Euler's identity, $e^{a + i~b} = e^{a} \cos b + i~e^{a} \sin b$ to reduce this to the solution:

$$y(x) =  c_1 \cos x + c_2 \sin x$$

You would need initial conditions to find $c_1$ and $c_2$.

Comment: But how do you know this? Can you solve this with seperation of variables?

Comment: Don't you use euler's identity when the discriminate is less than 0?

Comment: ahhhh I was dyslexic for the moment. Must be that I am sleepy of course the solution is imaginary thanks.

Comment: Nicely laid out! +1